# simple checkbox javascript doesnt work

Tags: javascript

The checkbox should be checked, but it doesnt work. I´m baffled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function check() {
document.getElementById("1").checked = true;
}
</script>

<form>
<input id="1" type="checkbox" name="please check" value="1">please check<br>
</form>
```

Comment: You can't have an id that starts with anything other than a letter.

Comment: @boz You can in HTML5.

Comment: How do you call `check` function?

Comment: Please post the full code here.. I mean where are you calling the function check() etc..

Comment: id="test" works neither

Comment: @VisioN - I had no idea. You learn something new every day :)

Comment: even if it could be legal, setting ids to only integer value is not really advisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have call it on Window Onload Where to call just pass function name

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=check;

    function check() {
    document.getElementById("1").checked = true;
    }
    </script>

    <form>
    <input id="1" type="checkbox" name="please check" value="1">please check<br>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Order it the other way and get rid of the function, this will make sure that the checkbox exists when the script runs.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/T4kYv/)

```
<form>
    <input id="1" type="checkbox" name="please check" value="1">please check<br>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("1").checked = true;
</script>
```

Alternatively put it on document ready (jQuery) or window load.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/qQeMZ/)

```
window.addEventListener('load', check);
function check() {
    document.getElementById("1").checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function check() {
document.getElementById("check1").checked = true;
}

window.onload = check;
</script>

<form>
<input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="please check" value="1">please check<br>
</form>
```

[refer this link also](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp).